# karma-opera-launcher gives no such file or directive ./config/prefs.ini error

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, opera, karma-jasmine

I'm getting this error after I run `karma start test/karma.conf.js`:

```
WARN [launcher]: Can not load "Opera", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

It seems to be because of this error:

```
WARN [plugin]: Error during loading "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-opera-launcher" plugin:
  ENOENT, no such file or directory './config/prefs.ini'
```

Full output:

```
~/code/simulated-selves $ karma start test/karma.conf.js
WARN [plugin]: Error during loading "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-opera-launcher" plugin:
  ENOENT, no such file or directory './config/prefs.ini'
WARN [preprocess]: Can not load "ng-html2js", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Safari
WARN [launcher]: Can not load "Opera", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
INFO [Safari 8.0.7 (Mac OS X 10.10.4)]: Connected on socket 7E_R6dTRtbdOIjPkKqiF with id 7465598
INFO [Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.4)]: Connected on socket AxabWkNzGr4EcGn9KqiG with id 52528925
INFO [Firefox 39.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.10.0)]: Connected on socket jGDy5qBGHsLPo8h6KqiH with id 72018902
Safari 8.0.7 (Mac OS X 10.10.4): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.017 secs / 0.014 secs)
Firefox 39.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.10.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.029 secs / 0.026 secs)
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.4): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.045 secs / 0.042 secs)
TOTAL: 3 SUCCESS
```

Why is this happening and what could I do about it?

I've successfully ran `npm install karma-opera-launcher --save-dev`. I have Opera installed on my computer and it works.

Edit - more details:

- I'm using Mac OSX 10.10.4.
- I get the same problem when I start with Opera open before running `karma start test/karma.conf.js`.
- I tried running `npm update` and `npm update -g` as well as updating node, and none of that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-opera-launcher/issues/7